# Changing name of ReturnUrl parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC application uses forms authentication configured in Web.Config. When the user navigates to a page that requires authentication he/she will be redirected to my login page. The url will automatically contain the parameter "ReturnUrl", e.g. "www.mysite.com/login?ReturnUrl=/pathToMyRestrictedPage". This is nice since I can use the parameter to redirect the user to that page after logging in.

My question is whether it is possible to change the name of the parameter "ReturnUrl" to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, ReturnUrl is default with the Microsoft Membership Provider. Maybe you can change the parameter when you write your own provider.